# semantic ui dropdown selecting by default issue

Tags: semantic-ui

**Semantic UI Dropdown was behaving like selection dropdown by default**

I have not initialised selection to this dropdown but it was acting like selection dropdown
I don't understand why it was showing me like that. please help me to find a solution for this issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/kd00bw5q/

```
<div class="ui dropdown">
<div class="text">File</div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">New</div>
    <div class="item">Make a copy</div>
    <div class="item">
      <i class="folder icon"></i>
      Move to folder
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <i class="trash icon"></i>
      Move to trash
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="item">Download As...</div>
    <div class="item">E-mail Collaborators</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.ui.dropdown')
 .dropdown()
;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean? The code you have posted here and the one in the fiddle is not the same.

Comment: The fiddle has few more items

Comment: Oh, okay .. +1 for 'finding it'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I finally found the solution**

**The problem is with the ".text" class. If the entire div with .text class removed the problem solved**

**Here is the updated code below**

```
<div class="ui dropdown">
<i class="file icon"></i> File
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">New</div>
    <div class="item">Make a copy</div>
    <div class="item">
      <i class="folder icon"></i>
      Move to folder
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <i class="trash icon"></i>
      Move to trash
    </div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="item">Download As...</div>
    <div class="item">E-mail Collaborators</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.ui.dropdown')
 .dropdown()
;
```

**Solved Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wgrkwnaw/**